# Perl как сделать таблицу?

Tags: perl, cgi

Есть база с колонками: дата, имя, прогресс, качество.
Надо сделать визуальное представление, для этого я делаю выборку с сортировкой по дате и создаю хеш многомерных массивов - `push @{$data{'name'}[$day]}, "$progress/rating";`

Не могу сгенерировать полную таблицу. Если указывать четко по каждому масиву, то работает:

```
print table(
  Tr(
    td('name'), td(@{$data{'name'}}[1]),
  ),
);
```

но надо показать все массивы, что то типа `[0 .. @{$data{'name'}}]`

Comment: У вас кроме {name} небось и другие колонки еще есть ? Может стоило бы данные хранить в виде `$data[$day]{name}`. И вот эта `table` - это из какого модуля. Я вижу что то очень похожее в CGI.pm правда там принято делать через экземпляр CGI и тогда это выглядит как `print $q->table` у вас же экземпляра не видно ...

Comment: Также можно конструировать таблицу скажем через `HTML::Table` там сами добавляете строки (причем можно это делать прямо в цикле чтения из БД, что бы вообще не генерить многомерные структуры в памяти)

Comment: да, это CGI.pm и через print тоже работает =)

Comment: что изменится от того что я поменяю с  `$data{'name'}[$day]` на  `$data[$day]{name}` ?

Comment: В том месте где создаете TR сможете сделать какой нибудь `map { tr(td($data[$_]{name})) } @data` хотя конечно и при текущем массиве можно но тогда его придется делать для какого нибудь for перебирающего возможные даты

Comment: я и так могу его использовать, но он не корректно работает. я пробовал `map{ td( @{$data{'name'}}[$_] ) } 0..@{$data{'name'}}`

Comment: Что значит некорректно работает ? Такая конструкция как вы написали должна выдать одну строку таблицы в которой будет много колонок в каждой из которых данные по одному дню

Comment: `push @{$data{'name'}[1]}, "111";
push @{$data{'name'}[3]}, "2222";
print table(
 Tr(
  map{ td( @{$data{'name'}}[$_] ) } 0..@{$data{'name'}}
 ),
);`
# <table><tr><td /> <td>111</td> <td /> <td>2222</td> <td /></tr></table>

Comment: Ну да, он напечатал именно, что вы его попросили. В массиве 4 элемента, 0й и 2й элементы пустые. Вот он и сделал таблицу из 4х колонок 2 из которых пустые. А что бы вы хотели видеть вместо этого ?

Comment: что за `<td />`?. сек проверю.

Comment: `<td/>` это то же самое, что `<td></td>` - т.е. пустая колонка

Comment: спасибо, что то я увидел это и подумал что глюк. не знал про пустую колонку.